# Concerning Problem 108 in "Open Problems in Topology"

Tags: gn.general-topology

In the book *Open Problems in Topology* by Jan Van Mill and George M. Reed, the following problem was presented:
108. *Is there a para- Lindelof Dowker space?*
Recall that a *para-Lindelof Dowker space* has a locally countable open refinement, satisfies Axiom T4, and is not countably paracompact. 
Some results on this problem are in http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v11/tp11203.pdf, where it is shown that the conditions are preserved under perfect mappings.
What is the status of this problem?
Any references are appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean for a space to have "a locally countable open refinement"$\:$? $\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky If a space has a locally countable open refinement, then it locally has the same cardinality of the natural numbers in a refinement $V$ (a cover such that for every $v\inV$ there exists $u\inU$ such that $V\subsetU$). 

Comment: .....and what does it mean for two sets to have "locally the same cardinality" ("in a refinement" or otherwise)?

Comment: Steven's first question is a good question. $\;\;$ Whatever the answer to that is, what you have in parentheses seems to be equivalent to $\: V\subseteq U \:$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Given that the question makes no sense and the OP has made no attempt to fix it, I'm having trouble understanding why it's still open.

Comment: I'm going to give Jaivir until your (Steven's) first comment is a day old. $\:$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is now problem 502 in "Open problems in topology II", I would guess it is still open.